# Выравнивание по центру изображения, которое больше контейнера

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы img был в центре, и обрезался равномерно с каждой стороны(сверху, снизу, слева, справа)

```
<div style="width: 120px; height: 120px; overflow: hidden">
  <img src="cat.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`object-fit: cover;`

[object-fit - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

```html
<div style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;">
</div>
```

Comment: к сожалению `object-fit` переопределяет размер картинки, а тут она задана в `html`, и тогда уж я бы использовал `object-fit:none`

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере известны размеры, поэтому осталось определить отрицательные отступы.

```
<div style="width: 120px; height: 120px; overflow: hidden">
  <img src="cat.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; display: block; margin: -40px 0 0 -40px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```css
img {
  /* сдвиг влево и вверх на половину размера картинки */ 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* сдвиг вправо и вниз на половину размера враппера */ 
  margin: 50% 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 120px; height: 120px; overflow: hidden">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTw8O.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
</div>
```

---

Или так, если можно менять размер картинки на оригинальный

```css
img {
 object-fit: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 120px; height: 120px; overflow: hidden">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTw8O.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
</div>
```